# How do I use protocol-relative URLs in IE9?

Tags: html, url, https, internet-explorer-9

**UPDATE**

This was neither IE9 nor the plugin. It was the fault of the person *using* the plugin.

**Original Question**

I have an image at `example.com/image.png` that I'd like to use in a Javascript plugin on both HTTP and HTTPS pages. The plugin currently sets the URL to

```
//example.com/image.png
```

Most browsers turn that into `http://example.com/image.png` or `https://example.com/image.png` propertly. When the page is viewed in IE9 over HTTPS, however, the URL gets turned into `https:////example.com/images.png`. That is, IE9 prepends `"https://"`, not just `"https:"`. How do I get IE9 to properly handle protocol-relative URLs?

Comment: Are you certain that this isn't the plugins wrongdoing?

Comment: I'm not absolutely certain, no, though it does work correctly on other browsers, which does diminish (though certainly not eliminate) the possibility.

Comment: @Sean Kinsey it's actually neither IE9 nor the plugin. It was the fault of the person using the plugin.

Comment: do submit a patch if you can ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot find out what is happening then you can easily resolve the url's yourself by passing `location.protocol + url` to the plugin instead of just `url`.